# Access token is null in Msal response-Azure AD B2C

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an SPA Vue.js app, using msal.js to connect Azure AD B2C to get the Id,access token and use the access token for furthur call to my APIs(which is a .net core webApi). So far I was using built in user flow and now I have to change to custom policy. I figured I don't get access token through custom policy.
Access token is null in msal response.

```
onToken:(ctx,error,response) => ...
```

I have defined my default scope in the SPA and Azure. If I run the custom policy in Azure AD b2c and set the Access token and select jwt.msas reply Url, I am able to see the access token in response. So I think there is nothing wrong with the custom policy. So it looks like I need to do some additional call with msal to Azure and get the access token.
I couldn't find any good document and I already tried AquireToken in msal, and it didn't work.
I am not sure if I have to set the response type in the initial msal authentication call to 'code, id-token' or 'id-token token'? Or how to do that? and If not what can I do to get the access token as I am in front-end and using implicit flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Response type should be or include token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes).

This [simple code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript#acquire-a-token-with-a-redirect) is all you need to get your access token (response type token is implicit):

```js
function authCallback(error, response) {
    // Handle redirect response
}

userAgentApplication.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback);

const accessTokenRequest: AuthenticationParameters = {
    scopes: ["{your b2c exposed api scope}"]
}

userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
    // Acquire token silent success
    // Call API with token
    let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Acquire token silent failure, and send an interactive request
    console.log(error);
    if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
        userAgentApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
    }
});
```